# Transform specified pandas columns into a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

**Current table:**

| source | target | value | group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | dog | 3 | 1 |
| Kate | cat | 4 | 2 |
| Sasha | whale | 5 | 3 |

**Desired output:**

```
list_dicts = [{'id': 'Bob', 'group': 1}, {'id':'Kate', 'group':2}, {'id': 'Sasha', 'group': 3}, 
              {'id': 'dog', 'group': 1}, {'id': 'cat', 'group': 2}, {'id': 'whale', 'group': 3}]
```

For the moment I am only able to do this:

```
df = df.to_dict('records')
```

I assume that to go further, I'd have to select the columns which I want to transform into list of dictionaries ? In this case I do not need the "value" column. #sendhelp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with specify columns for processing, then change order of columns and last convert to list of dictionaries:

```
L = (df.melt(id_vars='group', 
             value_vars=['source','target'], 
             value_name='id')[['id','group']].to_dict('records'))
print (L)
[{'id': 'Bob', 'group': 1}, {'id': 'Kate', 'group': 2}, {'id': 'Sasha', 'group': 3}, 
 {'id': 'dog', 'group': 1}, {'id': 'cat', 'group': 2}, {'id': 'whale', 'group': 3}]
```

If need processing all columns:

```
L1 = (df.melt(id_vars='group',
             value_name='id')[['id','group']].to_dict('records'))
print (L1)
[{'id': 'Bob', 'group': 1}, {'id': 'Kate', 'group': 2}, {'id': 'Sasha', 'group': 3},
 {'id': 'dog', 'group': 1}, {'id': 'cat', 'group': 2}, {'id': 'whale', 'group': 3},
 {'id': 3, 'group': 1}, {'id': 4, 'group': 2}, {'id': 5, 'group': 3}]
```